# Intuition for orthogonal vectors in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

Two vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ are orthogonal iff their dot product is $0$. I'm aware that the dot product can be defined in other spaces, but to keep things simple let's restrict ourselves to $\Bbb R^n$.

Given that the idea of orthogonality is roughly to identify when two vectors have no "overlap", **then apart from the fact that in $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ this corresponds to the geometrical notion of orthogonality**, why is this chosen as the definition of orthogonality? Ideally give examples of concrete mathematical problems where this definition arises naturally.

Comment: It does not only correspond to the geometrical definition of orthoganilty in 2 and 3 dimensions, but in all dimensions.

Comment: @Raskolnikov What do you mean?

Comment: How is the geometrical definition of orthogonality different in 10 dimensions from the one in 3 dimensions?

Comment: This question is virtually impossible to answer, because it is not clear what is being asked, and you present a confused idea of what orthogonality is about and seem to ask for help progressing in this confused view. Notably "having no overlap" for vector has neither any formal nor any intuitive meaning. You could be asking one of (1) why should orthogonality involve a notion of inner product (2) what properties should an inner product have intuitively (3) why does the dot product satisfy our intuitive requirements of an inner product, and in particular what we expect of orthogonality?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen But "having no overlap" is how Wikipedia introduces the concept of orthogonality almost verbatim.

Comment: So Wikipedia has a confusing description here. This adjective is used here to describe what orthogonality might mean in contexts _other_ than inner product spaces. I think the only one of the examples they mention where it might apply is that of term-rewriting systems. In any case it is definitely not relevant to this question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwan Perhaps the question I should be asking is simply: what is interesting about vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ whose dot product is zero?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let'd consider the geometry, to expand on Raskolnikov's comments:

Consider two independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Then there's a unique plane through them (and the origin). Pick a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^2$ that sends that plane onto all of $\mathbb R^2$ and preserves lengths. Then the vectors are dot-product-orthogonal in $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if their images are geometrically-orthogonal in $\mathbb R^2$ (use the converse of Pythagorean theorem or whichever other criterion you like). This says that the geometry in $\mathbb R^n$ really acts the same way as in $\mathbb R^2$.

---

However, you seemed to be saying that you were not interested in the geometry side of things, and wanted an independent reason why orthogonality of vectors is important. Pretty much everything in your linear algebra book about orthogonality is an example, with one of the biggest ones being the spectral theorem, which says that every nice linear map (given symmetric matrices in the $\mathbb R^n$ case) is just a linear combination of orthogonal projections.

Another important use of orthogonality is in the singular value decomposition, which has many applications, including [image compression and topography](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/applied/e3101/SVD_applications.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Orthoganility intuitively could be reflcted as "no dependency". It is deeply anchored in the intuition of *eigen*-space and *eigen*-vector and *eigen*-value, *eigen*-... Recall that *eigen* means in German *"the very geniune property of itself"*  and this relates to a property which is absolutely genuine to $A$ and not shared with any $B$. So keeping also in mind that *orthogonality* of *eigen*-properties is relative. Indeed in $\Bbb R^n$ it ties depply with the *dimmensions*. There, dimmensions represent the number of possible *eigen*-properties (*metaphoric:* absolute selfish properties). The term *orthogonality* is lent indeed from the *90 degree* or *perpendicular* $\perp$ visualisation of linear algebra but was by the mathematicians extended broadly to cover such type of relation that corresponds to *eigen*-properties under given constraints. From this point of view one should say *orthogonal* is a lent term that was used more and more expanded in its application to *genuine independency* and not restricted to be set identical to the term *perpendicular*.

***Example:*** generally applicable you can test any $A$ and $B$ relatively to each other and under your given constraints with respect to *orthogonality*. A beautiful one might be that two *theorems* $T_1$ and $T_2$ could be *orthogonal*.

Comment: The notion of eigenvector does not require, and hence has no relation to, an inner product structure. On the other hand the latter is essential for the definition of orthogonality.

Comment: Marc, this was an answer related intuitive roots of *orthogonality*, not only what is definition in algebra. The *inner product* equal zero definition applies of course as definition in algebra, you are right. The question however makes to me to be far more profound and braoder thought. Otherwise one may also expand the classical deifinition of *inner product*.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your answer. Could you give some concrete mathematical details?

Comment: As another example you can regards orthogonality in the mathematical context of morphisms e.g. isomorphisms.